# bitcoin core what is it all about does it make my desktop a server

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, server

when my bitcoin core finishes synchronizing does it make my desktop to be like blockchain.nfo where people can create wallets. and must i be online always. apart from that does it mean i have all the bitcoin history from 2009 till date on my hard drive .if my hard drive is compromised does it put all the bitcoin core information in my desktop at risk

Answer (score 1):

> when my bitcoin core finishes synchronizing does it make my desktop to be like blockchain.nfo where people can create wallets.
>
> and must i be online always.

No.

Bitcoin Core is purely a wallet, mostly for personal use.

When bitcoin core syncs it means it is downloading previous blocks / blocks that have ""happend"" while bitcoin core had no access to internet.

> apart from that does it mean i have all the bitcoin history from 2009 till date on my hard drive

Yes. It does mean you have all bitcoin transacations and blocks since 2009 on your computer.

> if my hard drive is compromised does it put all the bitcoin core information in my desktop at risk

It shouldn't if you have your wallet encrypted, otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will mean that you have a Full Node and a Wallet.

A Full Node allows you to fully validate transactions and blocs. You will have a native Bitcoin Core wallet already synchronized to you Node ready to use.

You can also connect other lightweight wallets you can have, such as, an Electrum Wallet, to your Bitcoin Core Full Node. To validate the transactions made from there. If not, the lightweight wallets depend on third party nodes that you must trust.

Your desktop will have the Bitcoin Blockchain at full, which means you will have Bitcoins entire transaction history. Unless you prune the node, which may be needed to save your computers memory. That would delete old blocks to save computer memory.

Your wallet won't be at risk, as long as it is encrypted.